# React Redux each child should have a unique prop error

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've been troubleshooting for the last 4 hours to no avail, still same error. Cannot find anything wrong with the code.

My code was displaying the items the correct way from the api but I done something and can't revert. Seems like it's through iteration on the deal items but I cannot figure it out. I've added screenshots to make it easier. Any guidance would be really helpful to me at this stage.

DealsList.js

```
// DEALS LIST CLASS
class DealsList extends React.Component{
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getDeals()
  }
 render(){
   const dealsList = this.props.deals.map(function(dealsArr){
     return(
       <Col xs={12} sm={6} md={4} key={dealsArr._id}>
         <DealItem _id={dealsArr._id}
           title={dealsArr.title}
           description={dealsArr.description}
           price={dealsArr.price}/>
       </Col>
     )
   })
   return(
     <Grid>
       <Row>
             <Basket />
       </Row>
       <Row>
         <Col xs={12} sm={6}>
           <DealsForm />
         </Col>
         {dealsList}
       </Row>
     </Grid>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    deals: state.deals.deals
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({
    getDeals:getDeals},
    dispatch)
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DealsList);`
```

DealsForm.js

```
class DealsForm extends React.Component{
  // constructor() {
  //   super();
  //   this.state = {
  //     images:[{}],
  //     img:''
  //   }
  // }

  handleSubmit(){
    const deal=[{
      title: findDOMNode(this.refs.title).value,
      description: findDOMNode(this.refs.description).value,
      price: findDOMNode(this.refs.price).value,
    }]

    this.props.postDeals(deal);
  }

  onDel(){
    let dealId = findDOMNode(this.refs.delete).value;

    this.props.deleteDeals(dealId);
  }
  render(){

    const dealsList = this.props.deals.map(function(dealsArr){
      return (
        <option key={dealsArr._id}>{dealsArr._id}</option>
      )
    })
    return(
      <Well>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Panel>
              <FormGroup controlId="title">
                <ControlLabel>Title</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter title"
                  ref="title"/>
              </FormGroup>
              <FormGroup controlId="description">
                <ControlLabel>Description</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter description"
                  ref="description"/>
              </FormGroup>
              <FormGroup controlId="price">
                <ControlLabel>Price</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter price"
                  ref="price"/>
              </FormGroup>
              <Button bsStyle="success" onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>Add Deal to shop</Button>
            </Panel>
            <Panel style={{margin:'20px'}}>
                  <FormGroup controlId="formControlsSelect">
                    <ControlLabel>Pick a deal to delete</ControlLabel>
                      <FormControl ref="delete" componentClass="select" placeholder="select">
                        <option value="select">select</option>
                        {dealsList}
                      </FormControl>
                  </FormGroup>
                  <Button onClick={this.onDel.bind(this)} bsStyle="danger">Delete Deal</Button>
            </Panel>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <Panel>
              <InputGroup>
                <FormControl type="text" ref="image" value="" />
                <DropdownButton
                  componentClass={InputGroup.Button}
                  id="input-dropdown-addon"
                  bsStyle="info"
                  title="Choose Deal Image">
                  {/* {imageList} */}
                </DropdownButton>
              </InputGroup>
              <Image src="" responsive/>
            </Panel>
          </Col>
        </Row>

      </Well>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    deals: state.deals.deals
  }
}
Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `DealsForm`. 
    in option (created by DealsForm)
    in DealsForm (created by Connect(DealsForm))
    in Connect(DealsForm) (created by DealsList)
    in div (created by Col)
    in Col (created by DealsList)
    in div (created by Row)
    in Row (created by DealsList)
    in div (created by Grid)
    in Grid (created by DealsList)
    in DealsList (created by Connect(DealsList))
    in Connect(DealsList) (created by RouterContext)
    in div (created by Main)
    in Main (created by Connect(Main))
    in Connect(Main) (created by RouterContext)
    in RouterContext (created by Router)
    in Router
    in Provider

Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `DealsList`. 
    in Col (created by DealsList)
    in DealsList (created by Connect(DealsList))
    in Connect(DealsList) (created by RouterContext)
    in div (created by Main)
    in Main (created by Connect(Main))
    in Connect(Main) (created by RouterContext)
    in RouterContext (created by Router)
    in Router
    in Provider



TypeError: payloadArr.map is not a function
    at totals (heap.js:38548)
    at dealcartReducers (heap.js:38530)
    at combination (heap.js:35759)
    at dispatch (heap.js:16180)
    at heap.js:38567
    at heap.js:38388
    at dispatch (heap.js:35867)
    at heap.js:11235
    at <anonymous>
```

Comment: Remove all the images from the question and add actual code instead. 3 years in stackoverflow, I think you should know better...

Comment: from all we can see if looks like `_id` isn't unique. I'm guessing it's `null`

Comment: @Dekel ok, and azium I will check this, thank you

Comment: Add the code that was in their images... That's what important here

Comment: @cala first two are warnings. Assign a unique key to each Col under Row. Second override componentWillMount function, log & verify your props. Two things to check here first: deals: state.deals.deals under mapStateToProps is pointing to the right data path. second: value of _id under deals array is unique.

Comment: Thanks Rishabh ill try this